# VSCode - Tab skips to next word

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have not changed any keybindings in my VScode configuration but recently i started to experience that whenever i press tab it almost has the same effect of skipping to the next section/word as pressing ctrl + right arrow (on windows).

I've checked other suggestions are sure that the toggle tab key moves focus is disabled.

Also tested it across multiple different file types.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you can provide a screenshot or gif of the problem you’re facing

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: 3) What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.